# How do I find the missing term in this geometric sequence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry if this is a simple question (this is my first time using this website), but how do I find the missing term in 13,...,208?

Comment: Hint:  in a geometric progression the ratio between successive terms is constant.

Comment: Suppose your geometric sequence is  $a, ar, ar^2$ for some $a$ and $r$.  Find $a$ and $r$ and then find $ar$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are consecutive terms of geometric progression then $b^2=ac$.
The missing term is merely $\pm\sqrt{13\times208}=\pm52$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if it's a geometric sequence, it means that $a_{n+1} = k a_{n}$. Therefore, what should be the relation between $a_{n+2}$ and $a_{n}$?

Answer (score 0):

The terms of the sequence are $13, 13r, 13r^2$. Hence
$$
13r^2=208
$$
from which we can solve for $r$(there are two solutions). The middle term you can compute as $13r$ (again two answers).